# Trying to connect via ethernet on trace32 debugger

Tags: debugging, trace, ethernet, trace32, lauterbach

I have tried to connect on a trace32 Lauterbach debugger via ethernet but I can't made it work. I can only connect via USB. I followed the steps from lauterbach website but a I can't check "full duplex" option. Could that be the problem?

[This is the problem I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxyAL.png)

Comment: I think your question is not really suitable for Stackoverflow. Better ask the Lauterbach support: https://www.lauterbach.com/tsupport.html
Anyway: I would guess that you have network issues. Can you connect to your debugger via USB? Ensure that the "IP address" is correct in IFCONFIG window of TRACE32. Ensure that the "device name" is correct in case DHCP is checked. Can you ping you device? You haven't said what PowerDebug you've bought, but I am pretty sure that you don't need the option "full duplex", which is inactive for all newer PowerDebug.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.